# How insert value in text field of custom cell from pickerview when user click on textfield?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uipickerview, custom-cell

I have a table view in which i am adding a custom cell. In custom cell i have a text field. In that text field i want to insert value from picker view. Picker view will open when user click on text field. I have following code for that purpose but i am not getting value in text field. code..

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath 
    {    
        NSString *identifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d-%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
        cell_object = (Custom_cell2 *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier]; 
        if(cell_object == nil) 
        {
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Custom_cell2" owner:self options:nil];
        }

        // Configure the cell...
        cell_object.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cell_object.txt_name.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        cell_object.txt_name.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
        NSArray *array = [array_from objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        NSString *cellValue = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  
        cell_object.txt_name.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",cellValue];
        cell_object.txt_time.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
        cell_object.txt_time.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
        //cell_object.txt_time.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
        //cell_object.txt_time.text =@"";
        return cell_object;
    }
```

above code for custom cell.

```
    -(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
    {
        myPicker.hidden=FALSE;
        UIToolbar *tool = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 44)]; //better code with variables to support view rotation
        tool.tintColor=[UIColor blackColor];
        UIBarButtonItem *space=[[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil] autorelease];
        UIBarButtonItem *doneButton =[[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(done)] autorelease];
        //using default text field delegate method here, here you could call
        //myTextField.resignFirstResponder to dismiss the views
        [tool setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: space,doneButton,nil] animated:NO];
        cell_object.txt_time.inputAccessoryView = tool;
        [myPicker addSubview:tool];
        //you can -release your doneButton and myToolbar if you like
        [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:myPicker];        
        return NO;
    }

    - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent: (NSInteger)component
    {
        if (pickerView == myPicker)
        {
            [cell_object.txt_time setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[array_time objectAtIndex: [pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]]]];
            [table_routine reloadData];
        }
    }
```

when i click on cell_object.txt_time then appear a picker view but it is not inserting value from picker in text filed.

what is mistake in this  code?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: How do u add the data into the picker ? as a  view or directly as title string ?

Comment: @booleanBoy i am adding data into picker from array.

Comment: Where do u add the textField and do u add it  as a contentView to the cell ?

Answer (score 0):

[pickerView selectRow:1 inComponent:0 animated:NO];
    textField.text= [array_name objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];

you can try this code for adding text from pickerview selection...

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you have set  and also add following line to your code when you are going to add the myPicker as subView.

```
    myPicker.delegate = self;
```

Comment: i have already set delegate and data source in header file and by nib file. And i add also as per ur answer but still it is not inserting value.

Answer (score 0):

Actually You cant set value of `UITableViewCell textlLabel` like this. for Any change in tableView you have to reload it or reload the Cell individually.

Solution is create an array and store your `pickerView` Value in that array.

then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
cell_object.txt_time setText: [array objectAtIndex: indexPath];
```

try this..